# inventory update in a pythonic way

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm working on a time-series problem, and I have a list of events such that each data point represent several objects being pulled from an inventory.
Each time the value reaches below some threshold, I want to add a constant number to the inventory.
For example, I want:

```
(threshold = 55, constant = 20)
70 60 50 45 30 0 -5 -75
```

to become:

```
70 60 70 65 70 60 75 25
```

Is there a "pythonic" way (pandas, numpy, etc...) to do it with no loops?

Edit: the addition of constant can occur multiple times, and only effect the future (i.e indexes that are greater than the observed index). This is the code I'm using right now, and my goal is to lose the for loop:

```
threshold = 55
constant = 20
a = np.array([70, 60, 50, 45, 30, 0, -5, -75])

b = a.copy()
for i in range(len(b)):
    if b[i] <= threshold:
        temp_add_array = np.zeros(b.shape)
        indexes_to_add = np.array(range(len(b))) >= i
        temp_add_array[indexes_to_add] += constant
        b += temp_add_array.astype(int)

print(b)
print('*************')
print('[70 60 70 65 70 60 75 25]')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're allowing for `numpy`:

```py
>>> import numpy as np

# threshold and constant
>>> t, c = 55, 20

>>> data = np.asarray([70, 60, 50, 45, 30, 0, -5, -75])

# if you allow for data == threshold
>>> np.where(data >= t, data, data + c*((t-1-data) // c + 1))
array([70, 60, 70, 65, 70, 60, 55, 65])

# if you enforce data > threshold
>>> np.where(data > t, data, data + c*((t-data) // c + 1))
array([70, 60, 70, 65, 70, 60, 75, 65])
```

But there is really no need for an external dependency for a task like that

```py
# threshold and constant
>>> t, c = 55, 20

>>> data = [70, 60, 50, 45, 30, 0, -5, -75]

# if you allow for data == threshold
>>> [x if x >= t else x + c*((t-1-x)//c + 1) for x in data]
[70, 60, 70, 65, 70, 60, 55, 65]

# if you enforce data > threshold
>>> [x if x > t else x + c*((t-x)//c + 1) for x in data]
[70, 60, 70, 65, 70, 60, 75, 65]
```

*Edit of OP*
I doubt there's a (readable) solution for your problem without using a loop; best thing I could come up with:

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.asarray([70, 60, 50, 45, 30, 0, -5, -75])

# I don't think you *can* get rid of the loop since there are forward dependencies in the the data
>>> def stock_inventory(data: np.ndarray, threshold: int, constant: int) -> np.ndarray:
...     res = data.copy()
...     for i, e in enumerate(res):
...         if e <= threshold:
...             res[i:] += constant
...     return res
...

>>> stock_inventory(a, threshold=55, constant=20)
array([70, 60, 70, 65, 70, 60, 75, 25])
```

Comment: This is almost what I need, the ((t-data) // c + 1) part can't be increased by more than one each step. in this example, this part in your code gives: [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 7]   but I need it to give:  [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

Comment: Adjusted reply to more specific question now

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a numpy ndarray...

- original array is named `a`
- subtract the threshold value from `a` - name the result `b`
- make a boolean array of `b` < 0 - name this array `c`
- *integer/floor divide* `b` by `-1 * constant` - name this `d` (it could be named `b` as it is no longer needed)
- add one to `d` - name this `e`
- use `c` as a boolean index to add `e` to `a` for those values that were less than the threshold. `a[c] += e[c]`

Comment: `np.where(data >= threshold, data, data + constant*((threshold-1-data) // constant + 1))` if value == threshold is allowed; `np.where(data >= threshold, data, data + constant*((threshold-data) // constant + 1))` else; hella messy though

Comment: @StefanB - You should post that as an answer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried it but it didn't work for me. Anyway, as far as I understand your idea won't work exactly as I want. I edited the original post for clarification